# Create a function to insert element into List at given position

Tags: c++, linked-list

Not sure if there is a simple and better way to implement this function?

```
void insert(Node* &head, int element, int position) {
    Node* current = new Node;
    current->data = element;
    current->next = NULL;

    if (position == 1) {
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
        return;
    }
    else {
        Node * current2 = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < position - 2; i++) {
            current2 = current2->next;
        }
        current2->next = current2->next;
        current2->next = current;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: position can be at any point you pass in,

Comment: you need to add null-checks because the position could be larger than actual size of list

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Some boundary check is needed (please find the comments inline):

```
int listLen(Node *head)
{
    int len = 0;
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        len++;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return len;
}

void insert(Node* &head, int element, int position)
{
    if (head == nullptr)    // do nothing if head is nullptr
        return;

    if (position < 0)   // insert to the begin if position is negative
        position = 0;
    else
    {
        int len = listLen(head);
        if (len < position)   // position is out of range, insert to the end
        {
            position = len;
        }
    }

    if (position == 0)
    {
        Node *next = head;
        head = new Node(element);
        head->next = next;
    }
    else
    {
        int curPos = 0;
        Node *curNode = head;
        while (curPos < position - 1)   // move to position
        {
            curNode = curNode->next;
            curPos++;
        }

        Node *next = curNode->next;    // do insertion
        curNode->next = new Node(element);
        curNode->next->next = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to make this function without null pointer access. You are missing all the necessary error checking.

But if you have to use this function you are already doing something wrong. The operation takes O(n) time. And if you build your list using only this function then you already have O(n^2) time. Using a balanced tree or heap would give you O(n * log n) time which makes a huge difference even for relatively small n. So think again why you need to insert at a given position and think about more suitable data structures.

A simpler implementation, and actually used in real code a lot, is to implement `insert_before(before, data)` or `insert_after(after, data)` with a doubly linked list. Both of which would get an item in the list and a new item to insert and place the new item before or after the old one on O(1) time.